# Adding a macro to Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, macros

There was a question on adding a macro in Outlook 2010 but the answer was a little unclear to me. I want a specific line of text to appear in an email that is sent to a specific group of people (example: agenda editors). It is "These are the current changes for July 23, 2012 (date automatically updates)." Where do I configure this or put the text for this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Sub Boilerplate_Agenda_Editors()

    Dim objMail As MailItem
    Dim allRecipients As Recipients

    Set objMail = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    Set allRecipients = objMail.Recipients

    allRecipients.Add "Your distribution list name inside the quotes"
    allRecipients.ResolveAll

    objMail.Subject = "Attention Agenda Editors"
    objMail.Body = "These are the current changes for " & Format(Now, "mmmm dd, yyyy") & "."

    SendKeys "^{END}"

    objMail.Display

    Set objMail = Nothing
    Set allRecipients = Nothing

End Sub
```

Editor and button help - http://www.slipstick.com/developer/how-to-use-outlooks-vba-editor/

Macro security should be set to medium.

Button help - http://www.howto-outlook.com/howto/macrobutton.htm

Comment: you can put this code into `Application_ItemSend` event instead if you want complete automation

Comment: @tumchaaditya - Only if you want every email you send to say the same thing, except for the date. :)

Comment: you could check whom the mail is being sent to in the macro..